How to replace character and split lines in python
I have a text file with a bunch of data like this:
DMG*D8*19931219*F**H~AMT*P3*0~NM1*31*1~N3*2670 SO A W GRIMES BO*#6102~N4*ROUND ROCK*TX*786642849~NM1*QD*1*FIGUEROA*LILIET~N3*2670 SO A W GRIMES BO*#6102~N4*ROUND ROCK*TX*786642849~INS*Y*18*024*07*A***TE~REF*0F*811229070~REF*1L*811229070~REF*3H*0~REF*ZZ*H~REF*6O*1055763324~DTP*303*D8*20240901~DTP*356*D8*20240201~DTP*357*D8*20250131~DTP*286*D8*20240831

I want to split the data into new lines where the ~ character appears.
I have tried:
with open(txtP835s + '/' + fileName, "r") as txtfile:
    for line in txtfile:
        line.replace('~', '\n')
        lines = line.splitlines()
    print(lines)

txtfile.close()

But this doesn't work. The data just looks the same as the raw file.

str.split() can take a substring parameter to tell it where to split: lines = line.split('~'). It can even be multiple characters long. Also, str.replace() returns a new string, it doesn't modify in place. You have to remember to save the result to a new string each time: line = line.replace('~', '\n') (but don't do that, just split directly).

Also, if your file doesn't already have newlines, then "for line in txtfile" seems odd.  I would do the replace on txtfile, assign the result (as suggested above) to a new variable, then split that result, and then loop through split data (lines in result, or whathaveyou).

Oh, and you don't have to call txtfile.close() when you use with - it's what's called a "context manager" and it will handle the teardown for you (in this case, closing txtfile) once you've left the indented section. So in summary, you can trim this down to just with (...) as txtfile: lines = txtfile.read().split('~') (assuming your file doesn't have newlines like Mike suggested). Godspeed, Ben.

You need to put print(lines) inside the loop. Otherwise it's just printing the last value of lines (assuming the file has multiple lines).

In your code, the replace('~', '\n') line isn't updating line in place, which is why it's not appearing with new lines when you print.
Instead, try saving the result of replace back to line and ensure you write out or print each transformed line individually.
with open(txtP835s + '/' + fileName, "r") as txtfile:
    # Read the entire file as a single string
    data = txtfile.read()
    
    # Replace each '~' with a newline character
    data = data.replace('~', '\n')
    
    # Split into lines and print each line
    lines = data.splitlines()
    for line in lines:
        print(line)

If you want to save this output as a new file:
output_file = 'output.txt'
with open(txtP835s + '/' + fileName, "r") as txtfile, open(output_file, "w") as outfile:
    data = txtfile.read()
    data = data.replace('~', '\n')
    outfile.write(data)

I hope this will help you a little.

for line in data.split('~'): would be more direct.  No need for replacement or splitlines.
